# How do you boot Arch Linux with systemd without X11?

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, systemd

Ran an upgrade recently that borked my whole setup(with catalyst drivers).  It caused artifacts at login/desktop and then a hard lock.  However, I'm not asking about those problems, what I want to know is, how do I boot without any X11 with the new systemd setup?

I run slim as my login manager(used to never use them for reasons like this) and run fluxbox.

So, I tried setting slim to auto-login, but would see the same problem on my desktop.  Then, I disabled slim, with `systemctl disable slim` and it would boot into my desktop(doing all this from single user mode).  I altered `~/.xinitrc` and commented everything out, but still, it would end up at slim instead of a tty login prompt.

Even using the kernel parameter `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`, which is supposed to be run level 3, in the grub gave me the exact same boot sequence.  I tried many other targets to no avail.  And Google basically gave me nothing but what I've already tried.

Is there any sure-fire way of booting without X11 with systemd?

Comment: how did you get to a terminal ? what i would try doing is booting into a arch linux install cd and chrooting into your existing system then running the #systemctl disable slim

Comment: Did you remove the symlink to the default login?  Try `rm /etc/systemd/system/default.target` and then symlink runlevel 3 target with: `ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target`.  No need to use what @dashboard said, since you can simply hit `F1 - F7` to change TTY prompts to various consoles and save a headache.  You can check the run-level with `systemctl list-units --type=target` if you feel so inclined.

Comment: @dashboard: I got to a terminal by trying to get to runlevel 3: `linux [...] 3` which in the case of systemd, just forces me into single user mode. "root password or ctrl+d" kind of stuff.

Comment: @nerdwaller: yes, by doing `systemctl disable default.target` it removes the symlink, so in `/etc/systemd/system/` the only thing there was the symlink to multi-user.

Comment: what happens when you do ctrl+f5 or f6 to get into a different tty?

Comment: @dashboard: Nothing, I can't get to another VC.

Comment: i know its a bit of work but i think your going to have to chroot into your system from a install cd....

Comment: @dashboard: That's what I'm doing, but doing that every X times to try and solve a problem is really time consuming.  Thanks, though.

Comment: No problem, i'm glad to suggest anything that can help.

Comment: Try moving /usr/bin/X to /usr/bin/X.backup (in other words, making it so X11 cannot start unless the new executable's name is invoked). When you're done, you can just move it back.